How to filter out the collection when loading into DataBricks
I have the following data in mongoDB

Document Data
{
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "2023-06-05T00:00:00.000+00:00"
}

I am loading this Mongo Data from a NoteBook inside DataBricks this way
dataFrame = spark.read \
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .option("database", "testdb") \
    .option("collection", "mycollection") \
    .option("uri", "mongodb+srv://myuser:IrvgcQDqvggSAXab@cluster0.re0lonc.mongodb.net/testdb") \
    .option("aggregation.pipeline", """[
                          {
                            $match: {
                             created_at: {
                                $gte: current_timestamp,
                              }
                            },
                          },
                        ]""").load()

What I am trying to do is that, I want to fetch only the documents that are greater than from current timestamp
But after executing the NoteBook , I see the data belongs to year 2023 is also coming .
